# Calling Java code from Flutter throws Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method...)

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, channel

I am working on a flutter project which necessarily has to call a java function. So, I defined my MainActivity.java just like this:

```
package com.manager.nlp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "analisisSintactico";

    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
                    if (call.method.equals("method")) {
                        result.success("value1");
                    } else {
                        result.success("value2");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

and I call it doing this from the main file in dart:

(I'll skip what's not important, like other Widgets and that stuff)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
class PaginaHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginaHome({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PaginaHomeState createState() => _PaginaHomeState();
}

class _PaginaHomeState extends State<PaginaHome> {
  static const cajaNegra = const MethodChannel('analisisSintactico');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: new Column(children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    invocarAJava();
                  }
                  ...
              )
         ...
         )
    }
    Future<void> invocarAJava() async {
       String valor = await cajaNegra.invokeMethod('method');
       print(valor);
    }
}
```

The, when clicking that IconButton, I get this error:

> E/flutter ( 9060): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)]
> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method method on channel analisisSintactico) E/flutter ( 9060): #0
> MethodChannel._invokeMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7) E/flutter (
> 9060):  E/flutter ( 9060): #1
> _PaginaHomeState.invocarAJava (package:holamundo/main.dart:146:20) E/flutter ( 9060):

If I run "flutter doctor -v" it says everything is correct
[image]

I also tried to execute flutter clean and then flutter run, having deleted de apk from the debug android emulator. It still shows the same error.

I know the file is being evaluated, because if I write something stupid, it detects the error. But, somehow, it does not recognize the method it is calling. Also tried with other names for the channel and the method.

Lastly, this is my build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.holamundo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

If anyone knows what the issue could be here that forbids me from calling my java code, I would gladly take any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- I am writing kotlin side but I think the problem is same. Move your methods to another java file as a Plugin Methods like this:

```
class AnalisisSintacticoPlugin(
        private val registrar: Registrar
) : MethodCallHandler,
        PluginRegistry.ActivityResultListener {

    private lateinit var _result: MethodChannel.Result

    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
            val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(),"analisisSintactico")
            val plugin = FlutterScreenRecordingPlugin(registrar)
            channel.setMethodCallHandler(plugin)
            registrar.addActivityResultListener(plugin)
        }
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
        if (call.method == "method") {
            result.success("value1")
        } else {
            result.success("value2")
        }
    }
}
```

2- Register it in your MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        val shimPluginRegistry = ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine)
        com.manager.nlp.AnalisisSintacticoPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.manager.nlp.AnalisisSintacticoPlugin"))
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** For java side:

1- Create a file called AnalisisSintacticoPlugin in same folder with MainActivity. Then pass this code:

```
package com.manager.nlp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;


public class AnalisisSintacticoPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
    private MethodChannel channel;

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), "analisisSintactico");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
        if (call.method.equals("method")) {
            result.success("value1");
        } else {
            result.success("value2");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null);
    }
}
```

2- Add your plugin in MainActivity:

```
package com.manager.nlp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull @NotNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.manager.nlp.AnalisisSintacticoPlugin());
    }
}
```

3- If not, change activity name in AndroidManifest.xml to ".MainActivity"

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
```

4- Make sure that meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml exactly same with this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />
```

Comment: I have never coded in kotlin. They're a bit similar but do you know how it would be done in java? Thanks

Comment: When I found solution for Java I will update my answer and leave a comment. I am trying now to make it work.

Comment: I edited my answer. I tried many solutions but finally I figured it out :D Anyway, it was nice, best luck my friend!